# Java Polymorphism and casting

Tags: java

In this code, shouldn't `(A) obj).test()` call the test method of class A? What am I missing?

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B obj = new B();
    obj.test();

    ((A) obj).test();
  }
}

class A {

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Called in A!");
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Called in B!"); 

    }
}
```

Comment: A cast only changes the type of the cast expression, it doesn't change the type of an object.

Comment: Agreed. Already asked and answered. I do find that an odd behavior.